# Is there any way of creating an equal value area by color on ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Let's say I have the following image:

[image]

I know that using `Global Mapper` I can create polygons around an area with a specific color. On the following example it's creating an area around the grey area:

[image]

This feature is called `Setup equal value area creation`. I'd like to do something similar with ImageMagick, is it possible? Can I draw areas according to the colors that I have in an image with ImageMagick (or get the polygon's coordinates just so I can draw them on the original image later)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is blurry, with all the colours really difficult to differentiate and it makes my eyes hurt. I also have no idea which part of it you are really interested in and what is just poor cropping/selection. So, I chose what I think are the things you might be interested in and separated out their colours so they are distinguishable from one another and got this:

```
magick 0N9iv.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill black -opaque "rgb(169,226,140)" -fill gray -opaque "rgb(212,208,204)" -fill white -opaque white \( +clone -colorspace gray -edge 1 -write edges.png \) -compose copyred   -composite result.png
```

[image]

Everything up to the opening parenthesis is just separating your objects. The part inside the parentheses makes white outlines and saves them for checking in a file called `edges.png`. The final part just colourises the edges and adds them back into the original.

I, or somebody else might be able to do better if you are clearer about what you are actually trying to do and what aspects of the image are important to you.

Comment: Your answer is already very close to what I'm trying to do. But I'd like to have it in the same image. So, instead of getting the red lines on a different image, could I instead get the polygon's coordinates? Just so I can draw them on the original image later?

Comment: The edges are already there in the file called `edges.png`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not exactly... I meant their number values, inside a vector or something like that. Then with these values, I could display the edges on the original image (doing this last part is not the issue, just getting their number values that is the issue for me)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"number value"*, sorry. Number value of what, please?

Comment: Let's say that the top margin of the image is the point [0,0]... So a polygon inside of the image would be a sequence of points inside an array. Something like [ [1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,1] ]... My assumption was that ImageMagick had this number values of the polygons that are being created. But I may be wrong.

Comment: I can't believe a list of coordinates of white points is gong to be the best way of doing anything, but if that's what you want, you can get them like this `magick edges.png txt: | grep "#FFFFFF"` You will get `X,Y: (255) #FFFFFF gray(255)` where X,Y are the coordinates of the white points.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want, but perhaps the following in ImageMagick. Suppose you measure the color at a location (150,60) in the large gray rectangle and want to draw another rectangle with the same color. Using ImageMagick 7,

Input:

[image]

```
magick img.png -set option:color "%[pixel:u.p{150,60}]" -fill "%[color]" -draw "rectangle 40,30 80,50" img_rect.png
```

[image]